# How can I use pandas agg here to avoid iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, chromosomes

can anyone help me improve this pandas code?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [
            'chr1', 222
        ],
        [
            'chr1', 233
        ],
        [
            'chr1', 2123
        ],
        [
            'chr2', 244
        ]
    ], columns = ['chrom', 'pos']
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [
            'chr1', 221, 223
        ],
        [
            'chr1', 230, 240
        ],
    ], columns = ['chrom', 'start', 'end']
)
```

Gives me 2 dfs with genomic coordinates. The first one is an exact position:

```
    chrom   pos
0   chr1    222
1   chr1    233
2   chr1    2123
3   chr2    244
```

and the second is a range:

```
    chrom   start   end
0   chr1    221 223
1   chr1    230 240
```

I need to find the count of exact coordinates that are in one of the ranges (in the same chrom)

This works but is slow:

```
c=0
for chrom, data in df.groupby('chrom'):
    tmp = df2.query(f'chrom == "{chrom}"')
    for p in data.pos:
        for s, e in zip(tmp.start, tmp.end):
            if s < p < e:
                c+=1
```

Then c = 2

I think I can use agg to do this without iteration (and hopefully faster) but I can't get it working. Can anyone show me how?

PS I am also asking this on stackoverflow.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is probably the best place to ask questions about optimising code.

Comment: That actually a really good question. A bioinformatics question. It's self contained and we'll explained. If U don't know just don't answer. No need for negatively.

Comment: I'm actually trying to help you, since code review (hint) is a much better place to get your code reviewed than either here or SO. You seem to be new here - so different sites have different functions. It's not about negativity / whether or not I can answer the question, it's about the correct questions are on the correct sites.

Comment: Ok fair enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# pip install pyranges or conda install -c bioconda pyranges

import pyranges as pr

g1 = pr.from_string("""Chromosome Start End
chr1   222 223
chr1   223 224
chr1   233 234
chr1   235 236
chr1   2237 238
chr1  2123 2124
chr2   244 245""")

g2 = pr.from_string("""Chromosome Start End
chr1    221  223
chr1    230  240
chr2    0 1000""")

r = g2.count_overlaps(g1)
r
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+
# | Chromosome   |     Start |       End |   NumberOverlaps |
# | (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) |          (int64) |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+------------------|
# | chr1         |       221 |       223 |                1 |
# | chr1         |       230 |       240 |                2 |
# | chr2         |         0 |      1000 |                1 |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+
# Unstranded PyRanges object has 3 rows and 4 columns from 2 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.

r.df
# 0       chr1    221   223               1
# 1       chr1    230   240               2
# 2       chr2      0  1000               1
```

Comment: How did I not know about pyranges!? Thanks!